# How to check if the command user has a specific role in discord?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

So I'm making a discord bot but I wan't to make some of the commands only usable by a specific role
Here is the code:

```
 @client.command()
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
 
  muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(I don't know if i should share this role id so just imagine there is a role id here)

  await member.add_roles(muted_role)

  await ctx.send(member.mention + " has been muted")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `has_role` decorator

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(198723981723) # Or the role name
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```

#### Reference:

- [`commands.has_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role)